# Machine Learning Algorithm for Identity Matching Against Watchlists

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I'm wrapping up Prof. Andrew Ng's excellent five-course specialization on [Deep Learning](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning) and am now looking for how I might apply machine learning to screening names against digital watchlists such as OFAC's [SDN](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/SDN-List/Pages/sdn_data.aspx) or [Consolidated Sanctions List](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/SDN-List/Pages/consolidated.aspx).  I currently have a solution that uses [Metaphone 3](http://www.amorphics.com/) and a normalized Levenshtein Edit Distance, but I would love to find some research papers that might show how I could build a Machine Learning solution to this problem to see if I can reduce false positives without significantly increasing the risk of false negatives.